# Different behavior from ubuntu server and ubuntu client on windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, shell-scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reading

cat /home/radiare/Desktop/first.txt | while read LINE

do
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo "Inside first loop"
break
fi
done

cat /home/radiare/Desktop/second.txt | while read LINE

do
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo "Inside second loop"
break
fi
done
```

In ubuntu client, I could able to execute this script and echo inside if statements are properly working. I did the same thing in ubuntu server it is not going inside the if statement. only difference is I run using sudo on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the issue with the "on windows" part in your question title?

Comment: My Ubuntu client is hosted on windows. There is no problem with it.

Comment: I would suspect the content of the files is different on your two machines.  Can you replicate this problem with `echo` rather than `cat`?  (Assuming that the script *is* exactly the same on both machines.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. files are replicas So the contents are same.

Comment: We can't really debug this for you -- you need to do the legwork here. Your best bet is to print `$LINE` before each `if` statement and see what's going on. (Also I have no idea what you mean by "ubuntu client" - do you mean Ubuntu Desktop Edition as opposed Server or Cloud editions?)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-x` after the shebang line so it looks like this: `#!/bin/bash -x`.  The output will look like this:

```
+ read LINE
+ cat /home/radiare/Desktop/first.txt
+ '[' true == false ']'
+ read LINE
+ '[' true == false ']'
+ read LINE
+ '[' false == false ']'
+ echo 'Inside first loop'
Inside first loop
+ break
+ read LINE
+ cat /home/radiare/Desktop/second.txt
+ '[' true == false ']'
+ read LINE
+ '[' true == false ']'
+ read LINE
+ '[' false == false ']'
+ echo 'Inside second loop'
Inside second loop
+ break
```

Note that I created a file with these contents for this test:

```
true
true
false
true
```

`second.txt` was a symlink pointing to `first.txt`.

I also ran it with `sudo` and got identical results.

Alternatively, you could add an `else` clause to see what the input looked like when it didn't descend into the `if` statement:

```
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]
then
  echo "Inside first loop"
  break
else
  echo "LINE is $LINE"
fi
```

Comment: value=$(</var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/my_mon.txt)
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo"Inside loop"
fi
This worked for me. Culprit is cat I guess